# Which dunder gets called in jupyter when I run an object alone in a cell

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-console

Let's say I have some `class_object_instance` of `some_really_complex_object` in my jupyter notebook.

Eg:

```
In [4]: import some_wild_proprietary_code as some_crazy_import
        class_object_instance = some_crazy_import.some_really_complex_object()
```

Then I run:

```
In [5]: class_object_instance
```

and I get:

```
Out[5]: <some_wild_proprietary_code.some_really_complex_object at 0x22918d68>
```

What is actually getting called when I run the cell?

I'd like to try to control the default behavior and have `Out[5]:` show somethign I could control, but maybe it's a jupyter-level thing and not a class object level thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the representation of the object by modifying the `__repr__` method.

Comment: Nice! Thanks you kind friend!